# Deploying .Net Compact Framework applications in windows mobile via msi file

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-installer

I was trying to generate a MSI file via a visual studio 2008 project which will install a/multiple cab file(s) to windows mobile via activesync(CeapMgr).

I used this as a reference : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446504.aspx

However when I install the application to the mobile phone(via activesync) by using the MSI, it adds an entry of the mobile application in the "Control Panel-Add/Remove Programs" of the PC in which the MSI is run, although the application is only supposed to installed in the mobile via activesync.

I do not want the entry in the Add/Remove programs of the PC.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is correct behavior.  MSI files do not get installed on the device.  Installation files for the device are CAB files.

The article you are looking at creates and MSI *that registeres the CAB file with ActiveSync/WMDC.*  When you connect your device, ActiveSync/WMDC then knows that the application is available for installation on the connected device and through the PC UI you can select to install the application.

If this is not what you are after, then you simply need to create the CAB file.  You don't need the MSI or the associated MSI installer project at all.  Just create the CAB, copy it to the target however you choose (USB, SD card, RAPI or whatever) and then run the CAB on the target.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the Add/Remove programs entry, perhaps you could make an EXE instead of an MSI to help install the CAB? Make a C# exe project, give it a simple dialog box with an "Install" button, and adapt the code from the "custom installer DLL" (in the article) to invoke ActiveSync.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Advanced Installer 7.7. (i have not used it to install mobile Apps) but i think it should work according to what you what